# CrossOrigin annotation doesn't work with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

When i enable the spring-boot-starter-security dependency. CORS support doesn't work.

This is my SecurityConfiguration Class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {

        return authentication -> {

          // ...
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf()

            // Disabling CSRF
            .disable()

            // Disabling Session Management
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            .and()

            // Adding custom REST Authentication filter
            .addFilterBefore(new RestAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), LogoutFilter.class)

            // Authorizing requests
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/frontend/login")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**", "/frontend/**")
            .authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

My Controller Class has a CrossOrigin Annotation:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/frontend")
@RestController
public class FrontEndController extends BaseController {
```

I can handle CORS with custom CORS Filter but I want to use just one Annoation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 methods for adding CORS support to spring-security enabled spring-boot project. We can add spring-web CorsFilter to security filter chain. The following example belongs to token based authentication project. So we used a custom RestAuthenticationFilter.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration               config = new CorsConfiguration();

        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        http.csrf()

            // Disabling CSRF
            .disable()

            // Disabling Session Management
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            .and()

            // Adding spring-web CORS filter
            .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(source), LogoutFilter.class)

            // Adding custom REST Authentication filter
            .addFilterBefore(new RestAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), LogoutFilter.class)

            // Authorizing requests
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/frontend/login")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**", "/frontend/**")
            .authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

But in the above example our CrossOrigin annotations in the controllers are redundant. So we should give the ability to control CORS requests to spring-web layer. Therefore we can allow CORS pre-flight (OPTIONS HTTP Methods).

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf()

            // Disabling CSRF
            .disable()

            // Disabling Session Management
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            .and()

            // Adding custom REST Authentication filter
            .addFilterBefore(new RestAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), LogoutFilter.class)

            // Authorizing requests
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/", "/frontend/login")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**", "/frontend/**")
            .authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

With the help of above configuration we can use both @CrossOrigin annotations and spring-security configuration.